# Как работают индексы с не числовыми типами данных?

Tags: c#, база-данных, postgresql, index

Во всех статьях по описанию работы индексов в качестве примера используют числа. Если id - число, то понятно, как создается кластерная таблица: id просто сортируется по возрастанию, ибо числа свободно сравниваются на больше/меньше/ равно. Что происходит, если Id - guid? Как он сортируется? Как реализуется b-tree, если индекс - строка? Сортировка идет по алфавиту?

Comment: Сортировка строк выполняется в лексикографическом порядке в соответствии с текущим COLLATION поля. Для дубликатов порядок не определён.

Comment: guid это тоже число, да всё в компьютере это числа.